# transaction is not getting roll backed with jta transaction manager

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, jta

I am new to Spring and hibernate please help,

I am using (Jboss 6.0 Final as Server)

org.springframework.transaction.jta.JtaTransactionManager

as bean with properties set

transactionManagerName as java:/TransactionManager and

userTransactionName as java:comp/UserTransaction.

In code I have set

```
jtaTxManager
```

property thr setters.

Then

```
javax.transaction.TransactionManager tx = jtaTxManager.getTransactionManager();
```

and then transaction is started using

```
tx.begin()
```

statement.

I have used

```
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
```

to get session of hibernate

at last I have used

```
tx.commit()
```

I am using hibernate to save multiple records within jta transaction
but If in between any database error occurs between some record like constraint violation exception getting thrown on tx.commit() which is

```
javax.transaction.RollbackException
```

which when catch I used to call tx.rollback() but  my transaction is not getting rollback and getting following exception on tx.rollback().I have not set any type auto commit property in hibernate properties.

But my first of records in gets saved in database ideally they should not saved but while rollback this exception occurs so i think that's why they are getting saved.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: BaseTransaction.rollback - [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.notx] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.notx] no transaction!
at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.BaseTransaction.rollback(BaseTransaction.java:158)
at com.arjuna.ats.jbossatx.BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.rollback(BaseTransactionManagerDelegate.java:114)
```

Comment: Have you started the transaction?

Comment: yes,But while rollback I am getting above exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to datasource configuration, forgot to mentioned earlier,

Removed from application-context.xml

**org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource**

and rather than this, used jndi datasorce of jboss configured in **oracle-xa-ds.xml**

Answer (score 0):

The Javadoc states that the RollbackException gets thrown when the transaction has been rolledback instead of commited - you don't have to rollback it manually in such a case, I think.
http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/transaction/Transaction.html#commit%28%29

Comment: Then on tx.commit();I am getting exception like javax.transaction.RollbackException: [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] [com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.transaction.arjunacore.commitwhenaborted] and still my earlier records get saved